# Rails: how to create an Object with another object as its attribute simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Customer object, which is just a holder for the People and Properties objects that will hold.

My problem seems to be that I want to make the Customer object and a Person object at the same time.

When I try to render the form to create the customer, there is a section for a form to create the Person. The Person needs the Customer's id, but apparently, that hasn't been created yet.

How can I make two objects simultaneously, one being the attribute of the first?

This is from my Customer controller:

```
 def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
@customer.update(params.require(:customer).permit(:customer_person, person_atributes: [:id, :firstname, :lastname] ))

        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is from the Customer form:

```
<snip>
<%= form_for([@customer,@customer.people.new]) do |f| %> 
<div class="field">
  <%f.label :firstname %><br />
  <%f.text_field :firstname %>
</div>
</snip>
```

Comment: Well.. you [read this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) step by step and implement it.. This is the code you want.

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is single table inheritance. Ie customer is a subclass of person but both are stored in the 'persons' table. http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

Comment: Thanks guys. I will look into both of your suggestions.